# Rust trait bound by supertrait with itself as generic parameter

Tags: rust

When working with a trait hierarchy, I got into the following problem: A trait (that is used as a trait object) should define a function that returns its own type. Of course, `Self` cannot be used since it would be different for each subtype. Instead, the trait should return the type of the trait object, like:

```
trait MySpecialTrait {
    fn clone(&self) -> Box<dyn MySpecialTrait>;
}
```

So far, this works. But now I want to extract this functionality in its own generic supertrait to be able to write generic code that only relies on the supertrait properties, like this:

```
trait Cloneable<Output: ?Sized> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Box<Output>;
}

trait MySpecialTrait: Cloneable<dyn MySpecialTrait> {
    fn something(&self);
}

fn clone_all<T>(data: &Vec<Box<T>>) -> Vec<Box<T>> 
    where T: ?Sized + Cloneable<T>
{
    data.iter().map(|x|x.clone()).collect()
}
```

But this code yields the following error:

```
error[E0391]: cycle detected when computing the supertraits of `MySpecialTrait`
  --> src\main.rs:28:1
   |
28 | trait MySpecialTrait: Cloneable<dyn MySpecialTrait> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: ...which again requires computing the supertraits of `MySpecialTrait`, completing the cycle
note: cycle used when collecting item types in top-level module
  --> src\main.rs:28:1
   |
28 | trait MySpecialTrait: Cloneable<dyn MySpecialTrait> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Using associated types like this does not change anything:

```
trait Cloneable {
    type Output;
    fn clone(&self) -> Box<Self::Output>;
}

trait MySpecialTrait: Cloneable<Output = dyn MySpecialTrait> {
    fn something(&self);
}
```

Can someone explain to me why there is a cycle? I understand that in the general case of `trait A: B` the supertraits of `B` have to be known to calculate the supertraits of `A`, so

```
trait A: B {}
trait B: A {}
```

cannot work. But in this case, `MySpecialTrait` is only referenced in the generic type arguments, so why is it required to compute the supertraits of `Cloneable<dyn MySpecialTrait>`?

Apart from that, is there are workaround for this problem?

**Edit**
I do not want `clone_all` to work only with all concrete subtypes of `Cloneable<T>`, but also with all trait types, e.g. I want to call `clone_all` with an argument of type `Vec<Box<dyn MySpecialTrait>>`.